# return value of match_results::size used with regex_search

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am not sure if I completely understand what is returned by `std::match_results::size`.
According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/size) it "*Returns the number of submatches*".

I am probably misinterpreting this description.
In my opinion that function is returning results for first occurrence, not for complete string.
`matches[0]` is a complete match, `matches[1]` is submatch and `matches[2]` is rest of the string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
    std::string s ("this subject has a submarine as a subsequence called subaru");
    std::smatch matches;
    std::regex pattern ("\\b(sub)([^ ]*)");   // matches words beginning by "sub"
    
    std::cout << "Target sequence: " << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Regular expression: /\\b(sub)([^ ]*)/" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The following matches and submatches were found:" << std::endl;
    
    std::regex_search (s, matches, pattern);
    std::cout << "size: " << matches.size() << "\n";


    std::cout << "Results: \n";
    while (std::regex_search (s, matches, pattern)) {
        std::cout << matches[0] << " " << matches[1] << " " << matches[2] << "\n";  // match, submatch, rest
        s = matches.suffix().str();
    }

  return 0;
}
```

based on:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/?kw=regex_search

**demo**:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/056462e884896604

Description suggests that in case of mentioned `string` call to `size()` should return number 4. (since there are four "subs" in sentence)
In practice `size()` returns matches and submatches, but only to first occurrence.
Is this function wrongly documented or I misunderstood how it works?

Comment: You misunderstand the reference. `regex_search` returns the first match. `matches.size()` returns the count of capturing groups in a regex + 1 (for the whole match).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
Thanks. Ok, I understand that this size() returns value only for the first match. ;)
Do you think that description on cppref is correct?
since size() returns capturing groups and complete match? (not submatches as it is documented IMO)